# Prevent users to view/delete file in sdcard

Tags: android

I have an internal app that can be distributed to company's users.

The admin can put a file to the device in specified folder in sdcard but don't want the users can view/delete it. What is the best way/concept to achieve it? Have tried researching it but still don't find good solution.

Comment: Do you have root access on the phone?

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih no, the company will not root the phone.

Comment: @ManishAndroid is it?

Comment: @ManishAndroid I use File Manager by Rhythm Software app in my phone but can view the . folder and its content and my phone is not rooted :(

Comment: @ManishAndroid you are wrong.  All data on the SD card is readable to any process and any user.  You can always take the card out, put it into an SD card reader and read/delete the file - then put the card back into the phone.

Comment: Yep, you don't need root to view hidden folders.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure it's even possible.  The user can always take the SD card out, put it into a card reader and view/delete it that way.  If your app relies on preventing access to a file on SD, then I'd say your design is flawed.

According to the android documentation, you should store *private* data in the internal storage and store *public* data in the external storage - have a look at the [storage options documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) for more info.

If you require to store/read files that users shouldn't be able to access other than through you app, then you should store these files in the local directory for the app (which would normally be under `/data/data/your.app.package`).  Use `openFileInput` and `openFileOutput` methods on a `Context` to read/write such files.

Comment: Yes I am totally agree with you. If there is no possible solution, I will discuss this with the company then.

Comment: +1 for _you should store these files in the local directory for the app,_ **but users can still delete files in local directory through Settings UI: Settings > Apps > [YOUR APP] > Clear data.**

Comment: @shoerat Yes, they could, however it's still quite a bit more secure than storing the files on the SD card.

Answer (score 1):

If your application uses some files then put these file into application's assets folder. If file present in sdcard then any one can view and delete.

Comment: The file can be changed anytime by admin, thus, can't be put in assets because need to recompile and reinstall everytime.

Comment: Another way is to store your file in database.

Comment: Can't too because the admin can change the content of the file anytime he wants.

Comment: if the content of file is changed by admin then update the file in to database.bt if you store any file in sdcard that is public to any one.